# Angular 7 (RxJs 6.x) - How to use throwError

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I want use second param (error) on my subcriber but dot not work.

**Code of my Observable:**

```
return Observable.create(obs => {
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return throwError(error || 'Server error');
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      return obs.next(data.User);
    }
  });
});
```

my `console.log(error);` is OK but after nothing (no trace).

**Code of my subscriber:**

```
this.myService.createUser(user).subscribe(
         result => this.getUsers(),
         error =>  this.errorUsersProcessor(error));
```

second param (error) on my subcriber never call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation : 
throwError

> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits > an error notification.

So my guess here is that the throwError is emiting an Error to a new observer not the one you are subscribing to.

You could try to notify you're actual observer to emit the error doing :

```
obs.error(error || new Error('Server error'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use pipe and the catchError operator. Can you try the code below:

```
this.myService.createUser(user).pipe(
     switchMap(response => this.getUsers()),
     catchError(err =>  this.errorUsersProcessor(error))
);
```